# DBContext dynamic load based on deployment environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, schema, entity, dbcontext

My database has different schemas for different environments like test/prod/stage. I tried to implement Adapative modeler. The issue with my DB is some of tables don't have Primary Keys which EF won't like. But those are read only tables. So i created different contexts based on environment. Now my problem how to load dbcontext based on web.config settings using single call.

```
var dcontext=Model.GetDBContext()


GetDBContext()
{
     if(test)
     {
         new testContext();
     }
     if(prod)
     {
         new prodContext()
     }
}
```

I couldn't figure it out how it will work for single variable name.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are needing help with: reading some config value from web.config and setting up your context according to that value?

Comment: yes  I can read config value then initiate DbContext based on environement

Comment: Your pseudo-code for `GetDBContext()` should be fine then, just insert `test` and `prod` with checks for your config value matching each environment.

Comment: But the issue is, What is the return type for Var variable since i can return any Dbcontext type like textContext() or prodContext(). Thats where i am stuck :(

Comment: Aren't you test and prod contexts of the same type? If not, do they derive from a common type?

Comment: same type means? Both are having same tables but only schema change. The Db is DB2. So schema issues coming for deployment environment. So i got both(test/prod) db contexts in VS and i kept a config setting in web.config so when we deploy we need to call production context.

Comment: For the record. Deleting [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976657/dbcontext-based-on-environment) and reposting them is considered bad practice (liable to a question ban). You should have edited your former question to improve it. This will also bump it back into attention.

Comment: if all the DBs have same tables, why dont you pass the connection string as parameter to the DBContext constructor? This will ensure you have the same 'Type' while connecting to different databases.

Comment: The issue is schema is different. for development its DEV and for prod its PROD.

Comment: can you please explain how the DEV and PROD schema are different?

Comment: In Db2 we want to access the table we will write query like select * from [schema].[tablename]. In my scenario the dev and prod schemas are different